# Bad Request 400 when performing update on Azure Table Storage entity with ETag matching

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I'm trying to get an entity, increment one of the property value, and then update it. This is the snippet my code

```
        var t = cc.GetTableReference("tableName"); 
        var query = new TableQuery();
        query.Where("PartitionKey eq 'myPartitionKey'");
        var res = t.ExecuteQuery(query); //this command executes succesfully
        var ent = res.FirstOrDefault();
        var num = ent.Properties["num"].Int64Value.Value;
        ent.Properties["num"].Int64Value = num + 1; 

        var updateOperation = TableOperation.Replace(ent);
        t.Execute(updateOperation, null,new OperationContext { UserHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "If-Match", ent.ETag } } });
```

If I remove the OperationContext, it will update successfully.

```
t.Execute(updateOperation);
```

Does anyone know what causes the error ? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Usually there will be more information with a 400 status. If you are getting a `StorageException` you can look at the `RequestInformation` property for more detail.

Comment: I don't think `new OperationContext { UserHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "If-Match", ent.ETag } } }` is needed, since SDK automatically adds ETag of the entity to the HTTP request headers.

Comment: you are right Zhaoxing thank you. I tested by querying two times, then update two times and the second update failed as expected. I'd like to accept your comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

Zhaoxing's comment above is the correct answer